# NIS/NFS Equalent for Windows

Tags: windows, active-directory, nfs, nis

Is there a Windows counterpart for the NIS/NFS implementation on Linux based systems where the entire user settings/ privileges / policies and most importantly the user files are stored on the server and the required user directory is remotely mounted when the user logs in?

I have tried out active directory, but I don't know of a way to store the user files (C:\Users directory) on the server and mounted as a remote share when the particular user logs in. This way the user could log in from any system and get his entire files and settings on any system on the network which is setup for this.

Also, I am not looking for a 'remote desktop' like setup and just want to get the files and settings to the client machine and the processing must happen on the local machine as opposed to the server.

Thanks in advance.
Shain P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for folder redirection:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732275.aspx

This can be set in a local system policy (gpedit.msc) or on an organisation unit in the Active Directory.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was what I was looking for. Please pardon my ignorance.